# Can I force pip to reinstall the current version?

Tags: python, pip, package

I've come across situations where a current version of a package seems not to be working and requires reinstallation. But `pip install -U` won't touch a package that is already up-to-date. I see how to force a reinstallation by first uninstalling (with `pip uninstall`) and then installing, but is there a way to simply force an "update" to a nominally current version in a single step?

Comment: for those looking to re-install pip it self (if it stopped working for some reason ;) ), the answer can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451650/pip-no-longer-working-after-update-error-module-object-is-not-callable) SO q&a

Answer (score 1266, accepted):

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>
```

When upgrading, reinstall all packages even if they are already up-to-date.

```
pip install -I <package>
pip install --ignore-installed <package>
```

Ignore the installed packages (reinstalling instead).

Comment: Any way to force an overwrite when using --target= flag? none of these worked for me.  I get the destination path already exists error.

Comment: @KeeganQuinn do you think that's what Karan meant by "When upgrading"...? I suppose so. But your clarification certainly helps me.

Comment: What if I want to make a change in zipline which is installed in the process of `pip install pipeline-live`, and simply pick up my change in zipline?

Comment: Including `--upgrade` when `--force-reinstall` is being used shouldn't be needed as of pip 10.0, FYI: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1139

Comment: While installing it saying `Using cached` for some packages, how to force their reinstall also?

Comment: @mrgloom The `using cached`just means it uses source files that where cached on the last install. To force re-download use the `--no-cache-dir` flag.

Comment: I don't want to reinstall any dependencies - only just the single package. Is this possible / how ?  Ah just see from next answer seems to be `--no-deps`

Comment: `pip install -U`, for short. (and the `--force-reinstall` option is rarely necessary)

Comment: Note that this command also reinstalls all dependencies.  Add `--no-deps` to avoid that, as suggested in Finn’s answer below.

Comment: This does not work for updating pip itself

Comment: "reinstall all packages", I don't understand what this does. You need to specify a package name, but it reinstalls every installed package? This is what I want to do, but I don't know which package-name to use.

Answer (score 305):

You might want to have all three options: `--upgrade` and `--force-reinstall` ensures reinstallation, while `--no-deps` avoids reinstalling dependencies.

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall <packagename>
```

Otherwise you might run into the problem that pip starts to recompile Numpy or other large packages.

Comment: This also works for offline installs, while the excepted answer doesn't.

Comment: This is a better solution for packages with a large number of dependencies that do not need to be reinstalled.

Comment: `sudo` was crucial in my case.

Comment: Why we need `--upgrade` when we use `--force-reinstall`?

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen why it should upgrade current version? as I understand here we want to reinstall package. What if `<package-name>==<package-version>` format is used?

Comment: @mrgloom `--force-reinstall` alone does not necessarily upgrade to the current version (at least not in pip 9.0.1). There has been an upgrade according to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1139 see cjerdonek's answer, so newer versions do not require the option.

Comment: Why do you have `sudo` here??

Comment: macOS: You shouldn't run sudo with pip on a mac . Run as admin rights user but without sudo .


On Linux (Ubuntu): it makes sense to run with `sudo` to install for all users. 
Don't run sudo with `--user` as that will install packages under `root` user only.

Comment: So by default all dependent projects likewise get updated too from the `--upgrade` flag, is that right?

Answer (score 62):

If you want to reinstall packages specified in a requirements.txt file, without upgrading, so just reinstall the specific versions specified in the requirements.txt file:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed
```

Comment: And if you want to avoid using the local cache, add the option  --no-cache-dir

Comment: This may still upgrade packages, though, if the version restrictions in the requirements.txt allow for it.

Comment: Indeed, but if you force them to a fixed version with '==' then no upgrades will happen

Answer (score 47):

```
--upgrade --force-reinstall
```

doesn't appear to force reinstall using python2.7 with pip-1.5

I've had to use

```
--no-deps --ignore-installed
```

Comment: You must specify `--upgrade` in addition to `--force-reinstall`, or it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 22):

```bash
sudo pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps --no-cache-dir <package-name>==<package-version>
```

Some relevant answers:

[Difference between pip install options "ignore-installed" and "force-reinstall"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913361/difference-between-pip-install-options-ignore-installed-and-force-reinstall)

Comment: --no-cache-dir is exactly what I was looking for, though the question isn't posed as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

In the case you need to force the reinstallation of **pip** itself you can do:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have a text file with loads of packages you need to add the ***-r*** flag

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a Jupyter notebook open using the python kernel that has the package loaded already. I closed that notebook and tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on MacOS and are using Homebrew, run:

`/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

of course use the appropriate path for your version

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --force-reinstall <package name>
```

this can be used

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?