# Issue with suds package installation

Tags: python, suds

```
Trying below code to check suds working   
 Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
    [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

            >>> from suds.client import Client
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
              File "suds.py", line 2, in <module>
                from suds.client import Client
            ImportError: No module named client

>>> exit()
```

When i try to install it again getting below error

sagarnig@sagarnig-HCL-Desktop:~$ sudo pip install suds
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): suds in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

after using -I

```
sagarnig@sagarnig-HCL-Desktop:~$ sudo pip install -I suds
[sudo] password for sagarnig: 
Downloading/unpacking suds
  Downloading suds-0.4.tar.gz (104kB): 104kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/suds/setup.py) egg_info for package suds

Installing collected packages: suds
  Running setup.py install for suds
    /usr/bin/python -O /tmp/tmpmktuLL.py
    removing /tmp/tmpmktuLL.py

Successfully installed suds
Cleaning up...
sagarnig@sagarnig-HCL-Desktop:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from suds.client import Client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "suds.py", line 2, in <module>
    from suds.client import Client
ImportError: No module named client
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sudo pip install -I suds
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549035/2896874).

Comment: found this issue on a old repo and the issue was it was using suds 0.4 which seems to prefer Python2. Running that pip command showed it could work with Python3 with version 1.0. Updated the requirements.txt and got past that error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the capitalized `Client`. You should use:

```
from suds.client import Client
```