# Encountering 502 re-installing django-haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I had previously successfully installed and tested out django-haystack, thought it wasn't what I wanted, and uninstalled it*. Now, I'm having trouble re-installing haystack. It's like a messy breakup/reconciliation situation.

In particular, adding ANY haystack settings OR `'haystack',` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in my settings.py file drastically breaks everything and I end up with a 502 response via Cloudflare, and Gunicorn telling me:

```
raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Forcing a [re-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548957/can-i-force-pip-to-reinstall-the-current-version) of django-haystack (thinking I might have uninstalled it incorrectly),
2. Uninstalling [django-silk](https://github.com/mtford90/silk/#installation), which I installed after removing django-haystack (thought it could be a case of 3rd party apps interfering with each other...),
3. Installing and running [django-watson](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson), and after finding out that it's not fast enough for my needs, uninstalling it (this one is just anecdotal I guess).

Any ideas?

---

*Don't know if this information will be of any use, but here's what I did when uninstalling haystack the first time round:

- `pip uninstall django-haystack`
- Removed all haystack settings from settings.py
- Removed `'haystack',` from `INSTALLED_APPS`

Even more info:

```
$ pip show django-haystack 
---
Name: django-haystack
Version: 2.4.0
Location: .../lib/python2.7/site-packages # truncated path
Requires: Django


$ pip show Whoosh
---
Name: Whoosh
Version: 2.7.0
Location: .../lib/python2.7/site-packages # truncated path again
Requires:
```

Comment: Could you check and see if you have `haystack` installed?

Comment: >>> import haystack
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/apps/django17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('The HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS setting is required.')
    ImproperlyConfigured: The HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS setting is required.



Does that mean `haystack` is somehow still installed? (sorry can't do code blocks)

Comment: Okay, this sounds a bit like what happened to me yesterday. Use pip to uninstall `haystack` and `django-haystack`. Then reinstall `django-haystack`.

Comment: # pip uninstall haystack
Cannot uninstall requirement haystack, not installed
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Then, I uninstalled `django-haystack`, and reinstalled:

Comment: # pip install django-haystack
Downloading/unpacking django-haystack
  Downloading django-haystack-2.4.0.tar.gz (160kB): 160kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:.../build/django-haystack/setup.py) egg_info for package django-haystack
    
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django in .../lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-haystack)
Installing collected packages: django-haystack
  Running setup.py install for django-haystack
    
Successfully installed django-haystack
Cleaning up...

Still getting the `502`..

Comment: Hmm, alright. Where is your django app located? What are the permissions for that directory? It might be that the directory requires root access. I'm assuming you're using nginx and gunicorn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81803/discussion-between-cssko-and-gx14).

Comment: Yup, nginx + gunicorn. I previously had trouble with `haystack` accessing the `whoosh_index` folder, but it's deleted now. To chmod the `whoosh_index` folder was the only access issue I had before this. My app's a typical folder in the Django project directory, I don't know how to get it to show permissions the system has on that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after getting some sleep! A spare `)` in `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` was the source of all my troubles..!