# pytesseract,WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, image-processing, image-recognition

I am new to text extraction.when i try to extract text from a png image using pytesseract as

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
s=Image.open('d:\\test.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(s))
```

I am getting error as
[image]
Is this the problem of image(test.png).the test.png is the image of a number plate.Should i need to install anything else.

Comment: Can you seperate the Image.open() call from the image_to_string call to see where the error occurs?

Comment: @tobspr Tried that But still getting same Error

Comment: Thats expected, the question is which line causes the error

Comment: @tobspr Line 3 is causing error

Comment: What is in Line 3 - the `Image.open` call or the image_to_string_call? You need to be more precise.

Comment: @tobspr, then next entry of the traceback is in `image_to_string` so it is the tesseract that is raising an error

Comment: @tobspr I have edited question.Now line 4 causing Error.pytesseract.image_to_string is causing Error.

Comment: @Ceem, it seems that pytesseract is trying to start a subprocess but the target of the subprocess (an executable file) is missing, can you try reintalling pytesseract? ([info to force reinstall here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548957/can-i-force-pip-to-reinstall-the-current-version))

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen reinstalled,Still same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to the [PyPi information](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) there is a perquisite that you are missing:

> Install google tesseract-ocr from http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ .
>   You must be able to invoke the tesseract command as "tesseract". If this
>   isn't the case, for example because tesseract isn't in your PATH, you will
>   have to change the "tesseract_cmd" variable at the top of 'tesseract.py'.

and that link redirected me to https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

I'm frankly disappointed that the package doesn't give you a more informative message that you are missing this, anyway once you have installed the underlying `tesseract` command pytesseract should work correctly :)

Comment: @it worked.Thanks.I installed tesseract-ocr from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/