# Which pip is with which python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, homebrew

This is driving me crazy. I have tried to remove all the packages of python installed on `mac os x` `el capitan` and re-installed `brew install python` and `pip`. Here I have :

```
which pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

and

```
which python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

so using `pip list`

```
pip list
cycler (0.10.0)
matplotlib (1.5.1)
numpy (1.11.0)
pip (8.1.2)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
pytz (2016.4)
setuptools (19.4)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.26.0)
```

However, when I run python, there is no module called numpy and matplotlib:

```
python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

and this is my `sys.path`:

```
sys.path
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

Comment: It is not saying there is no `matplotlib`, both error messages are saying there is no numpy.  Did you try reinstalling numpy?

Comment: what do you see when you execute `which pip` and `which python`?

Comment: Are you sure numpy compiled correctly? It depends on a bunch of C libraries. You could also try just ```pip install numpy``` to check the exit status. And finally, you could pip update pip itself just like ```pip install pip --update``` if that really is the issue here (which I doubt).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run `pip` with a specific version of Python by running it as a module. Command line arguments work just as if running directly from the command line. For example, try:

```
python -m pip list
```

If that still lists `numpy` it probably means there is something wrong with the `numpy` installation — i.e. the `.egg` file is there, but the module folder is not. To try and fix this you can use `--force-reinstall` with `pip`, e.g.

```
python -m pip install numpy --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

If that *still* doesn't work, you can resort to going to the folder reported by `sys.path` and deleting anything `numpy` related manually.

Since your `pip` setup seems messed up you might want to try reinstalling `pip` too!

Comment: I'd recommend trying to [force reinstall numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548957/can-i-force-pip-to-reinstall-the-current-version) before manually deleting files from the python installation folders.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thanks for the suggestion, much better first step.

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate method is to call `pip` from the specific python executable. For example:

```sh
/usr/bin/python -m pip list -v
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip list -v
```