# Install module in python locally

Tags: python, spyder, nibabel

I have a very basic question. I want to install a new module on my computer in order to use it in Python (via Spyder). When I install the package via pip everything seems to work fine. When I want to import the package in my script it says that there is no module by that name (see scrennshot below)

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Thanks a lot :)

[screenshot of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PPOO.png)

Comment: what's your `sys.executable`?

Comment: '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python'

Comment: and what about `pip3 -V` I think `pip3 -V` isn't belong to '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python'

Answer (score 1):

You're using `pip3` to install.

Try installing using `pip install nibabel`.

Failing that, I would refer you to the following question:
[Which pip is with which python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662012/which-pip-is-with-which-python)

This is a common pitfall of using different versions of Python and pip.

Comment: tried that as well. unfortunately it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question.
Have tried conda install 
Since we are in anaconda dev env.

If you are using windows
Windows: Click Start, search, or select Anaconda Prompt from the menu
and use that terminal
please find the reference
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/

Comment: conda install <package>

Comment: in the terminal you mean?

Comment: yes in the terminal / anaconda terminal try with  conda install <package>

Comment: if i type 'conda install nibabel' in my terminal it tells me "zsh: command not found: conda"

Comment: do you have anaconda on your system and is the python path added to your system

Comment: You are making another question, not giving an answer. This should go to `comments` section

Comment: i have anaconda on my system. not sure what you mean by python path added to my system

Answer (score 0):

I think

`/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python -m pip install nibabel`
or
`/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python -m pip3 install nibabel`

will solve your problem

Comment: ok there seems to be something really not working with the way i set up python/spyder. trying to execute it in my terminal throws a whole lot of error :/

Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
...
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Comment: wow that's a horrible error indeed. I have no idea