# pip no longer working after update error 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

After a pip update, pip has stopped working completely.

```
Z:\>pip install matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help please?

Edit: I am working on windows 10

Comment: Could you try `python -m pip install matplotlib` and report back the error ?

Comment: that appears to work

Comment: Make a habit of using `python -m pip`

Comment: There seems to be an issue regarding this [19.3 doesn't work after upgrading from 19.2.3](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7209)

Comment: @hansolo What's the reasoning behind this habit?

Comment: @AnnevanRossum Running `python -m pip` make sure that `pip` invoked is always associated with the `python` you are running

Comment: This fixed it for me: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7209#issuecomment-544696017

Comment: @hansolo There must be something else happening as well. On my system `pip` fails, while `python -m pip` succeeds. This is a multi-python system (and `pip3` succeeds as well as `python3 -m pip`). I was wondering if `pip` was used as is, it uses a different `PYTHONPATH` or does something else different.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum I tried ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` and it worked

Comment: This was https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 , voting to close because the pip bug was fixed long ago.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

All credit for this goes to user [han_solo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10392256/han-solo), who left the answer as a comment, instead of as an answer:

Instead of `pip install stdlib_list --user`

use `python -m pip install stdlib_list --user`

Replace `stdlib_list` with `matplotlib` or whatever the name is of the package you want.

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: yuck. but at least you can set an alias `alias pip="python -m pip"` (or `alias pip="python3 -m pip"`).  add that to ~/.bash_aliases or your shell rc file

Comment: use `python3 -m pip install stdlib_list --user` for python3. module name is still `pip` for this case.

Answer (score 14):

I've had the same issue as you, and I solved it uninstalling pip and installing again.

To uninstall:
python -m pip uninstall pip

To install, follow the instructions:
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/

After that you will going to have a older but functional 19.0.3 version.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not wish to use the long command every time `python -m pip install <package>`, reinstall pip to the older version where this error wasn't there.

```
python -m pip install pip==19.0.3
```

Now you will be able to use `pip install matplotlib` or `pip list` normally.

And whenever the bug is resolved, upgrade pip like you did before.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, uninstall pip 19.3.1 and replace with 19.0.3, error gone.

```
python -m pip install pip==19.0.3 --user
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @han_solo said, but if your running python3, instead of using:

`python -m pip install stdlib_list --user`

try using:

`python3 -m pip install stdlib_list --user`

Comment: Alden, Rather next time just edit the existing answer and add `python3 -m pip install stdlib_list --user` instead of having a whole new answer just to add a number

Answer (score 1):

Have the habit of installing any python packages with pip using *python -m*, say for installing *numpy* use below command:

**python -m pip install numpy**

In case if it errros out with the environment permission error append --user in the same command:

**python -m pip install numpy *--user***

Answer (score 0):

I cannot leave the comments yet, therefore I've decided to leave a link with an explanation why this can happen: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599

If this is the case you can try to fix it by downgrading the pip version with the following command:

```
 python -m pip install pip==<previous version>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with h5py-2.7.1, and the warnings were gone after upgrading to h5py-2.10.0.

Answer (score -1):

in one case, from your python file do this edit to your IMPORT

```
--import [MODULE]
++from [MODULE_NAME] import [MODULE]
```

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem. I've managed to fix it by reinstalling pip in place, using combination the other answers:

`python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall  pip`