# How to solve PIP update problem in Python3.6.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I tried to update **pip** in **Python 3.6.8**, after it update it's give me an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

When I open `cmd` and write `pip` it's give me same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip no longer working after update error 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451650/pip-no-longer-working-after-update-error-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: It's work when I use: `python -m pip`, but not work with: `pip`

Comment: activate your VENV and try: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python -x