# Cannot install python external package with pip main

Tags: python

I have external package and i want to install it by code inside my app, the code looks like :

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain            

pipmain(['install', module])

# NOTE : module is string package's name
```

but there is an error like : `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: You're trying to use pip in a way that's not supposed to be used. Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: You can not call pip in a python script. If you want to do an automatic installation I'd recomend you to write a .bat

Comment: @Ivan You can install a package this way. Though it's not a good practice, generally

Comment: Can you please add `module` in the code above?

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan module is just a string name of my own package, it's simillar like 'flask'

Comment: @Mamen yeah I get that. Can you specify it here?

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan i uploaded my own package with devpi so, my app can install it with external index url param, however the code above is working in 'flask run' environtment, but when i'm using uwsgi , the error is appears

Comment: @Mamen ohh, then you need to specify those in the question. How was I supposed to know that?

Comment: i found solution in this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451650/pip-no-longer-working-after-update-error-module-object-is-not-callable but don't know how to implement it @HenryHarutyunyan

Comment: @Mamen if that's the correct link, it's totally unrelated

Comment: Should you use only pip main to install the modules from the program? I mean is there a restriction ?

Comment: @Solen'ya yes because i've tried with subproccess it didn't work either

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan i've update, the code also didn't work for package from pypi.org ,it shows the same error

Comment: @Mamen can you use `os` to install by running `os.system("python3 -m pip install module")`

Comment: @Solen'ya i haven't tried it but thank you for your solution, i've just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

So after figuring out what happen, i've found the answer in [this github issue's comment](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7205#issuecomment-562564811)

it should be `pipmain.main()` not `pipmain()`