# Unable to execute Python script due to "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I'm trying to execute this basic Python script in Terminal (Mac) but it fails over when it's not able to find module.

Ran the same code into repl.it and works just fine so it's something on my machine which Python doesn't like.

Have attempted to install requests via:

> pip3 install requests

But that fails over with:

> m@mo-testmbp ~ % pip3 install requests        Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3",
>   line 10, in 
>       sys.exit(main()) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Python script:

```
    import requests
    from random import randint


    url = 'https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain'

    r = requests.get(url)
    text = r.text

    individual_words = text.split()
    random_num = randint(0,len(individual_words))

    print(individual_words[random_num] + str(random_num))
```

The code script fails with:

> m@mo-testmbp ~ % /usr/bin/python3 "/Users/m/OneDrive -
>   Mo/Training/Coding-mojoMac/Python/username_gen.py" Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/Users/m/OneDrive -
>   Mo/Training/Coding-mojoMac/Python/username_gen.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Have you tried installing `requests` using pip3 on the terminal of your computer, instead os VS Code? Otherwise perhaps try to reinstall pip3?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/44996#issuecomment-540674866  (in this case, I would try `rm -rf`ing `requests`)

Comment: Also, you may need `sudo`.

Comment: @BastienAntoine Yep went to Terminal first time but I've found the answer now so cheers anyways bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451650/pip-no-longer-work'module'%20object%20is%20not%20callableing-after-update-error-module-object-is-not-callable) could help you.

Try to use

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Or

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```