# how to expand pandas dataframe based on column value which is list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
Col1    col2     col3
test0   [1,2,3]  [ab,bc,cd]
```

Output dataframe I want is:

```
col1   col2  col3
test0  1      ab
test0  2      bc
test0  3      cd
```

There would be multiple column like col2 with same length of list

Comment: take a look at [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
outputdf_expandedcols=pd.DataFrame({
    "col2":df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['col2']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True),
    "col3":df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['col3']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
})

outputdf = df[['Col1']].join(outputdf_expandedcols,how='right')
```

`outputdf` will be:

```
    Col1  col2 col3
0  test0     1   ab
0  test0     2   bc
0  test0     3   cd
```

If you have more columns to expand you can use a [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
list_of_cols_to_expand = ["col2", "col3"] # put here the column names you want to expand
outputdf_expandedcols=pd.DataFrame({
    col:df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[col]),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True) for col in list_of_cols_to_expand
})

outputdf = df[['Col1']].join(outputdf_expandedcols,how='right')
```

Output same as above.

This answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element) thread.

Comment: will it work for the updated example?basically 1 in col2 has mapping with ab in col 3 and so on..

Comment: Now it will, yes.

Comment: Do you have col4 as well, with the same set-up as col2 and col3?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an up to date version of pandas, you can also do:

```
cols_to_expand = ["col2", "col3"] # or more columns if you have more
outputdf = df.explode(cols_to_expand)
```

`outputdf` will be:

```
    Col1 col2 col3
0  test0    1   ab
0  test0    2   bc
0  test0    3   cd
```

To have a compatible Pandas version in Google Colab, you need to run a cell (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549035/8565438)):

```
%%shell
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas
pip install -I pandas
pip install --ignore-installed pandas
```

then restart kernel (By clicking `Runtime`, then `Restart runtime`).