# BigQuery ImportError: Dlopen(...) library not loaded

Tags: python, import, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the google.cloud bigquery module, however I keep running into the following error during importing `from google.cloud import bigquery`
:

```
ImportError: 
  dlopen(/Users/rickwilde/opt/anaconda3/envs/summer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2):
Library not loaded: 
  @rpath/libarrow.900.dylib
Referenced from: 
  /Users/rickwilde/opt/anaconda3/envs/summer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-38-darwin.so
Reason: 
  image not found
```

I've checked in pyawrrow, and there is a file called lib.cpython-38-darwin.so

any help would be greatly appreciated

cheers

Comment: Have you resolved this issue yet? If so, did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the problem a few times too. From my observations, it happens when an executable or a library depends on another library, then that library is updated to a newer version. For me, simply reinstalling the program/library that gives this error has resolved it every time.

`lib-cpython-38-darwin.so` looks like it is related to CPython. My best guess would be that you've updated Python, so I'd try reinstalling the `google-cloud` package first. Like this:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall google-cloud
```

[This other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548957/can-i-force-pip-to-reinstall-the-current-version) might also help you.